# Where to share my JavaScript library?

Tags: javascript, forum

I've started making my own JavaScript libraries and want to share them so anyone can use them. Unfortunately I don't know any forums or sites I should publish my scripts on. Can you suggest me any of them? These libraries are not too big or relevant, but may come handy in some cases.

Comment: why do you downwote?

Comment: You can host them on github, you can create github pages with all your libraries.

Comment: Well this is better than a downvote thanks @jcubic

Comment: Someone downvoted because this type of questions are offtopic for SO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that the best site today is http://www.github.com.

After you can register your library at [www.npmjs.com](http://www.npmjs.com) or [bower.io](http://www.bower.io)